# Execute an EXE file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know how to execute an EXE file in Node.js. Here is the code I am using. It is not working and doesn't print anything. Is there any possible way to execute an EXE file using the command line?

```
var fun = function() {
  console.log("rrrr");
  exec('CALL hai.exe', function(err, data) {

    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
}
fun();
```

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can try the execFile function of the child process modules in Node.js.

Reference: *[child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback])](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)*

Your code should look something like:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var fun =function(){
   console.log("fun() start");
   exec('HelloJithin.exe', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
fun();
```

Comment: How can I run exce inside some folder like I want to run imagemagik command by using folder structure exec('C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16-HDRI/convert.exe convert -version', function(){
})

Comment: To add two arguments to the command for example '/t' and '600' add
`exec('HelloJithin.exe', ['/t', '600'], function(err, data) { 
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
   });`

Answer (score 17):

If the `exe` that you want to execute is in some other directory, and your `exe` has some dependencies to the folder it resides then, try setting the `cwd` parameter in options

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
/**
 * Function to execute exe
 * @param {string} fileName The name of the executable file to run.
 * @param {string[]} params List of string arguments.
 * @param {string} path Current working directory of the child process.
 */
function execute(fileName, params, path) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(fileName, params, { cwd: path }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        });

    });
    return promise;
}
```

[Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Node.js or any front-end framework that supports Node.js ([React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) or [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js))

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');

const child = execFile('chrome.exe', [], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

If the **.exe** file is located somewhere in the machine, replace **chrome.exe** with the path to the application you want to execute
e.g `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

```
const child = execFile('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', [], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever think about using Batch file in this process? I mean start a .bat file using Node.js which will start an .exe file at the same time?

Just using answers in the top, I got this:

1. Creating a .bat file in exe file's directory
2. Type in bat file
   `START <full file name like E:\\Your folder\\Your file.exe>`
3. Type in your .js file:
   `const shell = require('shelljs')`
   `shell.exec('E:\\Your folder\\Your bat file.bat')`