# How to exec .exe file from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe, node-webkit

im using NWJS to create a simple desktop app. I need to connect console c++ app when I do a click event in a button on html5. I heard it's possible using 'child_process' internal module from Nodejs. I didn't get to exec the exe file when I click in the button.

I have next code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var cmd = 'Test.exe 1';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // command output is in stdout
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error:', error);
    }
});
```

The .exe file has a input parameter (a number) and it returns a simple text with the introduced number.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js

Comment: I think that dup answers the question, albeit the target was written in C++, this is not a C++ question.

Comment: You are right! I'll edit that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should give this a try

```
child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback])
```

---

```
file <String> The name or path of the executable file to run
args <Array> List of string arguments
options <Object>

    cwd <String> Current working directory of the child process
    env <Object> Environment key-value pairs
    encoding <String> (Default: 'utf8')
    timeout <Number> (Default: 0)
    maxBuffer <Number> largest amount of data (in bytes) allowed on stdout or stderr - if exceeded child process is killed (Default: 200\*1024)
    killSignal <String> (Default: 'SIGTERM')
    uid <Number> Sets the user identity of the process. (See setuid(2).)
    gid <Number> Sets the group identity of the process. (See setgid(2).)

callback <Function> called with the output when process terminates

    error <Error>
    stdout <String> | <Buffer>
    stderr <String> | <Buffer>
```