# node.js webdriverio / webdriver.io Upload file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, webdriver-io

How to upload a file in wdio?

The element that allows you to select a file to upload (the normal way) is just an 'Upload File' clickable link.

[image]

Source:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="fileupload1" name="DocumentCreatedFileId" 
ng-hide="Model.Uploading" pl-upload="" pl-progress-model="Model.Percent" 
pl-auto-upload="true" ng-disabled="disabled" pl-files-model="Model.Files" 
pl-filters-model="filter" on-file-added="Uploading(true)" 
on-file-uploaded="Uploading(false)" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" 
pl-max-file-size="20mb" pl-url="/api/storage/upload" 
pl-flash-swf-url="/content/moxie.swf" 
pl-silverlight-xap-url="/content/moxie.xap">Upload File</a>
```

I've tried `browser.chooseFile(documentsAddPage.uploadFile, 'X.png');`, but I get the webdriver.io's favourite error - `selector needs to be typeof 'string'`

The `documentsAddPage.uploadFile` is `{  get: function () { return browser.element('#fileupload1'); } },`

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that the special needs child, that is node.js+webdriverIO, can deal with AutoIT scripts.

Use this code, that I copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js/), to run .exe files.

```
var fun = function() {
  console.log("rrrr");
  exec('CALL hai.exe', function(err, data) {

console.log(err)
console.log(data.toString());
  });
}
fun();
```