# How to run executable file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried this way..

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'executable.exe';
var path = 'c:\\path';
var child = exec(
      cmd, {
        cwd: path
    },
   function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error === null) {
            console.log('success');
     } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
  );
```

But still getting error `Error: spawn UNKNOWN`. Any idea why I am getting this error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute an exe file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js)

Comment: I am unable to execute .Any idea for my problem.