# How to Execute .exe file using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have a `.exe` file and I need to open that file during a middle of the automation script using protractor. How can I do that?

Comment: please, add more details. `HTML` parts, screenshot, etc.

Comment: In general protractor tests web based apps. While you can test the upload/download of a file, Running a .exe file is likely outside the scope of protractor

Comment: Actually I have created .exe file using AutoIt,So in order to run that file when ever it is required,using protractor-typeScript is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute an exe file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js)