# How to open a notepad using node

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am creating a project that my node project can open a notepad.exe

```
const openyeah = "notepad.exe";
const fs = require("fs");

fs.open(openyeah,"r",(err,fd)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('errors')
    }else{
        console.log("correct")
    }
})
```

Comment: Hope this link will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to get this done. The child_process module provides the ability to spawn child processes which enable us to open window programs like notepad,exe

If you look at the below example once we create a spawnObj, we can pass the pass the program name which needs to be executed as a first argument (in our case the `notepad.exe`) and the relevant input as the second input (in our case the `.txt file name`. Please check and replace the `C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/somefile.txt` in the below example with a valid path/filename in your PC).

```
var spawnObj = require('child_process').spawn,
progToOpen = spawnObj('C:\\windows\\notepad.exe', ["C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/somefile.txt"]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is just my example question bro but do you have any idea about running ccleaner auto clean using the same method?

Comment: In that case you will have to omit the `["C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/somefile.txt"]` argument here `progToOpen = spawnObj('C:\\windows\\notepad.exe', ["C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/somefile.txt"]);` and also instead of `notepad.exe` you need to call the `ccleaner.exe` with its relevant path.

Comment: I dont know about the array part bro? because there is no other file to open

Comment: var spawnObj = require('child_process').spawn,
progToOpen = spawnObj('C:\\windows\\CCleaner64.exe', ["C:\Program Files\CCleaner>ccleaner.exe/auto"]);

Comment: This would do => `var spawnObj = require('child_process').spawn, progToOpen = spawnObj('C:\\windows\\CCleaner64.exe'); `

Comment: error bro what is with that windows? is it really necessary to put ?

Comment: May I know where exactly the `CCleaner64.exe` is located in your PC?

Comment: C:\Program Files\CCleaner

Comment: I can open now but It should auto clean when open this is the only syntax

Comment: C:\Program Files\CCleaner>ccleaner.exe/auto'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189942/discussion-between-david-r-and-allen-cris).

Answer (score 0):

fs.open is for reading and writing to file content, but starting program is not "open" but "invoke" a (executable) file.

Answer (score -1):

you can also try

```
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');
exec("notepad.exe");
```