# Can we use AWS-CDK within another application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html) on `AWS-CDK` has examples of setting it up as a standalone application with support in multiple languages.

I have the following questions regarding the same:

- Is it possible to use it within a separate app (written in .NET Core or Angular) like a library?
- By above I mean being able to instantiate the construct classes within my app's services and create stacks in my AWS account.
- If yes, how does it affect the deployment process? Will invoking the `synth()` function, generate the cloud-formation templates as expected?

Apologies if my question is vague. I am just getting started with this and am willing to provide  necessary details if needed.

I appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using cdk as a library, but had a few issues and started calling it from another app by using a cli call.

I was using typescript and basically what I did was to call the `synth` method on the app construct:

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';

const app = new cdk.App();
... // do something
const cf = app.synth(); // here you get the cloud assembly
cf.something() // you can manipulate the results here
```

A few issues I found was to get errors during `synth` as they were not proper bubbled up.
I couldn't find a way to deal with the assets either...

In summary, I didn't explore it much further than that, but I think cdk might need more development to be able to use all its features when importing as a library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I agree that the CDK needs some more improvements to be able to use it as a lib. But could you elaborate on the "calling it from another app by cli" part ?

Comment: I mean by using an exec library to call the cdk cli tool from within the ts code as you can do with any executable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try it out.