# Discord bot that can can run an app from a command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command

I was wondering if I can get my bot to start an application on my computer? if i use a command like

```
    if (message.content === 'grimm!start-minecraft')
```

is there a way to start an .exe file from a command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to run any `.exe` but it'll run that file on the pc you're hosting the bot on. Not the client's computer (That'd be weird)

```js
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var runExe =fileName => {
   exec( fileName , function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                  
    }); 
}
runExe();
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js) out

Comment: Thanks for helpin me out! I still have one issue, I made another line of code so the app could open on command, `client2.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === "grimm!login")
    exec('Client.exe', function(err, data) {  ` but i get an `exec is not defined` how could i fix this?