# how to execute an exe file inside node.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
var exec = require('child process').execFile;
exec('C:\something.exe', function (err, data) {
     console.log(err)
     console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Check out this stack overflow answer that will resolve your query.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19762411/12843137

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the `exec` function from the built-in `child_process` module as shown in the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('start program.exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: 'installer.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
i get an error when i execute with the above method